# How can the query select the highest letter in a column based on the primary key?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
SELECT
  [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id, [Cat Total by Case].category, 
  [Filtered Charge Level].[Charge Level], 
  [Cat Total by Case].[Case Level Suggested]
FROM [Filtered Charge Level] 
INNER JOIN [Cat Total by Case]
  ON [Filtered Charge Level].casemain_id = [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id;
```

Now that I have the output wanted, I want it to determine based on the casemain_id to display the highest letter (according to D, C, B, A) along with the category.

I have tried the following code with no luck:

```
SELECT
  [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id, [Cat Total by Case].category,
  [Filtered Charge Level].[Charge Level], 
  [Cat Total by Case].[Case Level Suggested]
FROM [Filtered Charge Level] INNER JOIN [Cat Total by Case] 
  ON [Filtered Charge Level].casemain_id = [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id
Max(Cast(substring(OrderNo, D, Len(orderno)A) AS INT)) From [Cat Total by Case].[Case Level Suggested] Where orderno like 'ord-%';
```

The original code produces this:
[image: Case ID Category Level Suggested 256789 equipment D 256789 tray B]

The output I want is the code to recognize D is larger than B and only show:
[image: [Case ID Category Level Suggested 256789 equipment D [1]]

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output. That isn't valid SQL syntax. What happens when you open query?

Comment: When I run it, it says syntax error (missing operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT [Cat Total by Case].*, [Filtered Charge Level].[Charge Level]
FROM (
    SELECT casemain_id, Max([Case Level Suggested]) AS [MaxOfCase Level Suggested]
    FROM [Cat Total by Case]
    GROUP BY [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id) AS Query1 
INNER JOIN ([Cat Total by Case] 
INNER JOIN [Filtered Charge Level] 
ON [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id = [Filtered Charge Level].casemain_id) 
ON (Query1.[MaxOfCase Level Suggested] = [Cat Total by Case].[Case Level Suggested]) 
AND (Query1.casemain_id = [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id);
```

Or need a unique identifier field in [Cat Total by Case]. An autonumber type field should serve.

```
SELECT [Cat Total by Case].*, [Filtered Charge Level].[Charge Level]
FROM [Cat Total by Case] INNER JOIN [Filtered Charge Level] 
ON [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id = [Filtered Charge Level].casemain_id
WHERE ((([Cat Total by Case].[ID]) In (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM [Cat Total by Case] AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.casemain_id = [Cat Total by Case].casemain_id 
    ORDER BY Dupe.casemain_id, Dupe.[Case Level Suggested] DESC)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add

```
ORDER BY [Filtered Charge Level].[Charge Level] DESC
```

as the last line of code in your example, it will sort the result by [Charge Level] but "backwards".

Comment: There are 2 categories attached to the ID. I want it to output only the highest letter with D as the highest and not show the category if it is lower.